# Pattern matching with guards vs if/else construct in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching, guard-clause

In ML-family languages, people tend to prefer pattern matching to `if/else` construct. In F#, using guards within pattern matching could easily replace `if/else` in many cases.

For example, a simple `delete1` function could be rewritten without using `if/else` (see `delete2`):

```
let rec delete1 (a, xs) =
    match xs with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs' -> if x = a then xs' else x::delete1(a, xs') 

let rec delete2 (a, xs) =
    match xs with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs' when x = a -> xs'
    | x::xs' -> x::delete2(a, xs')
```

Another example is solving quadratic functions:

```
type Solution =
    | NoRoot
    | OneRoot of float
    | TwoRoots of float * float

let solve1 (a,b,c) = 
    let delta = b*b-4.0*a*c
    if delta < 0.0 || a = 0.0 then NoRoot 
    elif delta = 0.0 then OneRoot (-b/(2.0*a))
    else 
        TwoRoots ((-b + sqrt(delta))/(2.0*a), (-b - sqrt(delta))/(2.0*a))

let solve2 (a,b,c) = 
    match a, b*b-4.0*a*c with
    | 0.0, _  -> NoRoot
    | _, delta when delta < 0.0 -> NoRoot
    | _, 0.0 -> OneRoot (-b/(2.0*a))
    | _, delta -> TwoRoots((-b + sqrt(delta))/(2.0*a),(-b - sqrt(delta))/(2.0*a))
```

Should we use pattern matching with guards to ignore ugly `if/else` construct?

Is there any performance implication against using pattern matching with guards? My impression is that it seems to be slow because pattern matching has be checked at runtime.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if/else statements must be evaluated at runtime too...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right answer is probably *it depends*, but I surmise, in most cases, the compiled representation is the same. As an example

```
let f b =
  match b with
  | true -> 1
  | false -> 0
```

and

```
let f b =
  if b then 1
  else 0
```

both translate to

```
public static int f(bool b)
{
    if (!b)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Given that, it's mostly a matter of style. Personally I prefer pattern matching because the cases are always aligned, making it more readable. Also, they're (arguably) easier to expand later to handle more cases. I consider pattern matching an evolution of `if`/`then`/`else`.

There is also no additional run-time cost for pattern matching, with or without guards.

Comment: What if there is a 'when' in the patterns? Does the compiled representation change?

Comment: It just adds nested `if`s. It's all still compiled. In almost all cases pattern matching and the equivalent `if`/`then`/`else` will compile to the same code.

Comment: Actually, in my experience, complex pattern matching compiles to more efficient code than complex if/then/else statements, because the compiler does a decent job of removing redundant conditional evaluations on your behalf.

Comment: I assumed good code either way, but there you go: another reason to use pattern matching.

Answer (score 10):

Both have their own place. People are more used to If/else construct for checking a value where as pattern matching is like a If/else on steroids. Pattern matching allows you to sort of compare against the `decomposed` structure of the data along with using gaurds for specifying some additional condition on the parts of the decomposed data or some other value (specially in case of recursive data structures or so called discriminated unions in F#).

I personally prefer to use if/else for simple values comparisons (true/false, ints etc), but in case you have a recursive data structure or something which you need to compare against its decomposed value than there is nothing better than pattern matching.

First make it work and make it elegant and simple and then if you seem some performance problem then check for performance issues (which mostly will be due to some other logic and not due to pattern matching)

Comment: +1 for the 'decomposed' part. It's actually a good point to differentiate between pattern matching and if/else construct.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Daniel that pattern matching is usually more flexible.
Check this implementation:

```
type Solution = | Identity | Roots of float list

let quadraticEquation x =

    let rec removeZeros list =
        match list with
        | 0.0::rest -> removeZeros rest
        | _ -> list
    let x = removeZeros x

    match x with
    | [] -> Identity // zero constant
    | [_] -> Roots [] // non-zero constant
    | [a;b] -> Roots [ -b/a ] // linear equation
    | [a;b;c] ->
        let delta = b*b - 4.0*a*c
        match delta with
        | delta when delta < 0.0 -> 
            Roots [] // no real roots
        | _ ->
            let d = sqrt delta
            let x1 = (-b-d) / (2.0*a)
            let x2 = (-b+d) / (2.0*a)
            Roots [x1; x2]
    | _ -> failwithf "equation is bigger than quadratic: %A" x
```

Also notice in https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/learning-fsharp/ that it is discouraged to use if-else. It is considered a bid less functional.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing on a self writen prime number generator, and as far as i can say there is "if then else" is significantly slower than pattern matching, can't explain why though, but I as far as I have tested the imperativ part of F# have a slower run time than recursive functional style when it come to optimal algorithms.